# Jupyter Install on Debian 8

Tags: debian, jupyter

Has anyone successfully installed Jupyter on Debian 8?  I've run into several walls and need some input on how to proceed.

I've installed pip, pip3 and with them installed and upgraded jsonschema, however, Jupyter seems to be looking in my Python 2.7 directories.  pip installation seems to be missing packages or something.

Comment: Did you try to download and install Anaconda?

Comment: Yes, twice.  It's now solved, not sure if it was an Anacoda or Debian issue.  
My solution was:
apt-get purge -y python-pip
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
python ./get-pip.py
apt-get install python-pip 
From this blog:
https://odedrabhavesh.blogspot.in/2017/02/importerror-no-module-named.html

Answer (score 0):

Install the required packages:

```
apt-get install build-essential python3-all python3-pip libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev libzmq3-dev
```

Install jupyter:

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
pip3 install jupyter
```

Answer (score 0):

When you type  `pip3 install jupyter --user`, jupyter is in `~/.local/bin`, which is not in the path. (pip prints a warning about it)
so, if you want `bash` to find jupyter, you must edit the `.bashrc` file and add the new entry to the path:

```
PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin

echo "PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin" >> .bashrc
```